# Вызов метода из класса, реализующего интерфейс

Tags: c#, ооп, интерфейс

Для проверки работы необходимо вызвать метод из класса, реализующего интерфейс, например (`someContext` тоже интерфейс).

```
class Calc : cCalculate
{
    public void Calculate(someContext context){ //do something}
}
```

Как вызвать метод Calculate из другого класса, какой параметр передать?

```
class Programm
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
        Calc clc = new Calc();
        clc.Calculate(параметр?);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну какой-то класс же реализует интерфейс `someContext`? Сделайте экземпляр этого класса и передайте в `Calculate`. Ну или получите его откуда-то. А если у вас какой-то `DI` фреймворк используется, то укажите это в вопросе. Тогда, возможно, нужно конфигурить `DI` и он сам тогда может передавать такие штуки в конструктор.

Comment: Примечание: интерфейсам в дотнете принято давать имена с префиксом `I`: `ICalculate`, `IContext`.

Comment: Вопрос непонятен, чего именно хотите добиться?

Comment: Проверить, как выполняется метод Calculate из класса Calc. Есть по сути только класс Calc и в нем методы от интерфейса, остальная реализация скрыта. Добавляется как скрипт расчетов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот простой пример.

```cs
public interface ICalculator
{
    int Calculate(int a, int b);
}

public class Divider : ICalculator
{
    public int Calculate(int a, int b)
    {
        return a / b;
    }
}

public class Substractor : ICalculator
{
    public int Calculate(int a, int b)
    {
        return a - b;
    }
}
```

Тип созданного объекта в коде можно привести в этом случае к интерфейсу.

Может пример не очень красивый, но показывает, что метод ничего не знает о конкретной реализации переданного ему экземпляра `ICalculator`, но за счет интерфейса знает, что может вызваеть его метод.

```cs
static void ExecuteAndPrint(ICalculator calc, int a, int b)
{
    int result = calc.Calculate(a, b);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ExecuteAndPrint(new Divider(), 6, 2);
    ExecuteAndPrint(new Substractor(), 6, 2);
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
3
4
```

Если же используется конкрентный тип, как из вашего примера, то интерфейс в данном случае никак не используется, и с классом, реализующим интерфейс можно работать точно так же, как с любым другим.

Comment: Мне не доступен класс, реализующий интерфейс `someContext`. Я пробовал сделать такой класс, но там возникает еще одна проблема: присутствует метод, который возвращает еще один интерфейс, вроде `public IContextItem Attribute (string str){}`, что запутывает еще больше.

Comment: @11112222 так используйте интерфейс, обращайтесь с ним как обычным классом. Интерфейс - это всего-лишь тип, такой же как класс в плане вызова методов. Я не могу к сожалению вас распутать, потому что код, о котором вопрос видите только вы.